# Default in parameter throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

In one of our xUnit tests, we have a method with `in` parameters, one of which is default:

```
private void Method(in ClassA token, in ClassB model, in bool validate = false)
{
    if(validate)
    {}//do stuff
}
```

The method was called without specifing the validate parameter, like that:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod();
{
    var token = new ClassA();
    var model = new ClassB();
    Method(token, model);
}
```

For some reason, on one dev's machine, the `validate` parameter throws `NullReferenceException` both in run as well as debug. Doesn't happen on other.
Removing the `in` keyword fixes the issue.

The question is - can/should the `in` keyword be used with default parameters? And can it break like that randomly? Looking through the documentation I couldn't find any implication that it would.

Comment: this does not compiles i guess

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: What would make you think that?

Comment: That should be fine. I suggest you work to reproduce the problem on the machine that it fails on, and edit the question with a complete repro. (Ideally a console app we can just copy/paste/compile with no need to get XUnit etc.) My guess is that you'll find the code hasn't rebuilt properly or something similar.

Comment: Can you please write the exact code line the exception refers to being thrown of?

Comment: @JonSkeet this `var token = ClassA` does not look familiar to me

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I missed parenthesis during instantiation. The code breaks when I try to use the validate parameter in the if statement.

Comment: you are missing `new` keyword too

Comment: My guess is partly based on `Method` being private. You are not calling it from the test method at all, you are calling something else overloaded. Now when I guess overloading is involved, removing the `in` changes the signature so which method is called now? - the one you had before you inserted the `in`? Why do I guess this? because having optional parameters in public methods is a not a good idea as it is the caller(!) that gets the default value compiled into it. So the malfunctioning machine has an old caller. But `Method` is not public. So... track down what really is called.

Answer (score -1):

Using 'In' on the value type 'bool' I am guessing would force it to be 'boxed' into a reference type.  I wonder if having a default value and not passing a value in causes it to be boxed before it has any value resulting in a null reference?

Question is why does it behave differently between machines.  It must be how this c# syntax feature is actually compiled and maybe the runtime on the two different machines?

The bit I do not get is why do you need to use the 'in' keyword on a value type like bool.  Even if the value of the bool gets changed inside the method this can have no effect up the stack as it is a value type.  Also the purpose of the 'validate' boolean is purely to validate or not...

Comment: We use `in` keyword on value types to make them readonly references, and prevent them from copying, while also insuring they are not changed in the method. In this one example, where we cought it - the keyword is not strictly necessary, but we use it in production code too, in plenty different places and methods. The question arose if it breaks in this one place - can it also break in others, and should we be wary of using it?

Comment: No, there's no need for boxing for `in` parameters or indeed `ref` parameters. I do agree that using `in` for `bool` is pointless though.

Comment: @DemoBytom: While you wouldn't be copying the value of the `bool`, you'd be copying the storage location - which may well be less efficient than just copying the value. I wouldn't start using `in` all over the place without measuring the performance improvement. It's really designed for cases where you want to avoid copying a *large* struct.